# Mathematica values new list

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, dataset

I have a list:

```
data = {{2.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {4.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {6.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {8.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {1.*10^-8, 0.0025}, {7.*10^-9, 0.0023}, {3.*10^-9, 0.0025},...}
```

And I wanted to remove every third pair and get

```
 newdata = {{2.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {4.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {8.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {1.*10^-8, 0.0025}, {3.*10^-9, 0.0025},...}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way

```
MapIndexed[If[Divisible[First@#2, 3], Nothing, #1] &, data]
```

**Update**

One way to iterate is to use `Nest`.

```
filter = MapIndexed[If[Divisible[First@#2, 3], Nothing, #1] &, #] &;

data = Range[20]; (* Easy to see what is removed *)
Nest[filter, data, 5]
(* {1, 2, 14, 20} *)
```

To see intermediate steps

```
NestList[filter, data, 5] // Column
```

Comment: Is it possible to iterate this command 5 times?

Comment: @AgataBielecka Updated the answer to show one way to iterate.

Answer (score 16):

There are many ways to do this, but my favorite is to use the the stride and end arguments in [`Drop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Drop.html):

```
Drop[data, {3, -1, 3}] === newdata 
(* True *)
```

Comment: Of course  ! ;) This is the most simple answer.

Comment: I was wrong; THIS is the most direct way to do it ;).

Answer (score 9):

```
Riffle[data[[;; ;; 3]], data[[2 ;; ;; 3]]]
```

Answer (score 6):

If you ask me, this is the most direct approach:

```
Delete[data, List /@ Range[3, Length[data], 3]]
```

Answer (score 4):

I am sure there are many ways to do this. One direct way could be to build the index and use it to select the entries.

```
data = {{2.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {4.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {6.*10^-9, 
    0.0025}, {8.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {1.*10^-8, 0.0025}, {7.*10^-9, 
    0.0023}, {3.*10^-9, 0.0025}};
```

And now

```
idx = Table[If[Mod[n, 3] != 0, n, Nothing], {n, 1, Length[data]}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now use the new index

```
data[[idx]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Another way to construct the needed indices:

```
data[[Union[Range[1, Length[data], 3], Range[2, Length[data], 3]]]]

{{2.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {4.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {8.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {1.*10^-8, 0.0025}, {3.*10^-9, 0.0025}}
```

Similarly:

```
data[[Complement[Range[Length[data]], Range[3, Length[data], 3]]]]
```

Comment: Or `data[[NestList[a=1;i=1; a|->a+ RotateRight[{2,1},i++][[1]],a,\[LeftCeiling]2/3 Length[data]\[RightCeiling]-1]]]`

Answer (score 3):

Using `Partition`, padded with `Nothing`

```
Flatten[Take[#, UpTo[2]] & /@ Partition[data, 3, 3, {1, 1}, Nothing], 1]
```

Comment: Also, maybe, `Partition[data, UpTo[2],3]//Catenate`

Comment: @user1066 Thanks, very interesting.  I also learned from xzczd's double span answer.

Comment: Slightly shorter, lol `Join@@Partition[data, UpTo[2], 3]`

Answer (score 3):

```
newdata = data;
newdata[[3 ;; ;; 3]] = Nothing;
newdata
```

If it's OK to overwrite `data`, then simply

```
data[[3 ;; ;; 3]] = Nothing;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Table[
  If[Mod[n, 3] != 0, data[[n]], Nothing], {n, 1, Length[data]}]
```

Comment: This approach was already mentioned in Nasser's answer above

Comment: Almost. He used the extra step of generating the indices and then using those to select the elements of the data list.

Answer (score 2):

My two answers :-)

```
data[[Select[Range[Length[data]], Mod[#, 3] != 0 &]]]
```

and

```
Transpose[Select[Transpose[{data, Range[Length[data]]}], Mod[#[[2]], 3] != 0 &]][[1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[data, _-> Nothing, 3 ;; ;; 3]
```

{{2.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {4.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {8.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {1.*10^-8, 0.0025}, {3.*10^-9, 0.0025}}

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{2.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {4.*10^-9, 0.0025},
       {6.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {8.*10^-9, 0.0025},
       {1.*10^-8, 0.0025}, {7.*10^-9, 0.0023}, 
       {3.*10^-9, 0.0025}};
```

---

Using `PositionIndex`:

```
Keys[Select[PositionIndex[data], ! Divisible[#[[1]], 3] &]]
```

> {{2.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {4.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {8.*10^-9,
> 0.0025}, {1.*10^-8, 0.0025}, {3.*10^-9, 0.0025}}

Answer (score 1):

**Using `SequenceReplace`:**

```
data = {{2.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {4.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {6.*10^-9, 
    0.0025}, {8.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {1.*10^-8, 0.0025}, {7.*10^-9, 
    0.0023}, {3.*10^-9, 0.0025}};

SequenceReplace[data, {a_, b_, c_} :> Sequence @@ {a, b}]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{2.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {4.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {8.*10^-9,
> 0.0025}, {1.*10^-8, 0.0025}, {3.*10^-9, 0.0025}}